# изменение минимальной высоты контейнера

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня div, с id="container". Его минимальная высота прописана в CSS: `min-height: calc(100% - 184px);`. Мне надо, чтобы при вызове JS-функции theBestFunction min-height этого блока изменялась на такое значение: "100% высоты экрана минус 100 пикселей". Вот, как я пытался сделать это (оно не работает): 
`function theBestFunction() {
document.getElementById('container').style.minHeight = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - 184);
}`

Comment: `100% высоты экрана` - `100vh`

Comment: Мне "100vw" выдало как ошибку, теперь вообще функция на вызов не реагирует (100vh - тоже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function theBestFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.minHeight = "calc(100vh - 100px)";
}

theBestFunction();
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Это работает

Comment: С Новым годом :)